# Displaying the publication list so the user can opt-in from a cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, ssjs

I want to create a cloud page where it displays all the publication lists and from those user can select and subscribe in any of the publications.Just like in the subscription center. As I am new to marketing cloud and ampscript any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to interact with the SOAP API which can either be done using AMPscript or Server-Side JavaScript. To fetch all publication lists you need to do a retrieve on the List object. Just be sure to filter on the ListClassification-property for the value PublicationList.

**An example request to retrieve all publication lists looks like this:**

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">ACCESS_TOKEN</fueloauth >
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>List</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ListName</Properties>
                <Properties>ListClassification</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ListClassification</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>PublicationList</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Further resources:**

- [Retrieve a List from an Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_a_list_from_an_account.htm)
- [Retrieve All Lists a Subscriber is On](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_all_lists_a_subscriber_is_on.htm)
- [Manage Subscriber Status for One or All Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/managing_subscriber_status_for_one_or_all_lists.htm)
- [Create a Custom Profile Center with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm)